# Using PANDAS to conditionally manipulate specific cells based on another cell and getting it to change original df

Tags: pandas

```
andrew_ramirez[andrew_ramirez['Datacenter'].isin(['ATL2','ACT1'])]['payout']*= 0.25
```

This is not changing my dataframe (named andrew_ramirez) based on the criteria. Am i missing something?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: This question needs a [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org/). Please see [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html). Always provide a complete [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example").

Answer (score 0):

You can use from this code:

```py
df['payout']=np.select([df.Datecenter.isin(['ATL2', 'ACT1']), [df.payout*0.25], df.payout)
```